# Insert anchor links just before keyword occurrences on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

Basically, I'm combining here 2 jQuery plugins: SearchHighlight and TotalStorage (stores values into an easily retrievable cookie).

So, after keywords are entered into **Google searchbox**, google results are shown and visitor clicks chosen link. He gets to the page and **keywords he used for searching** are given yellow background. However, this is not good enough for my client - he asked me to make it so that the visitor is brought directly to location(s) of keywords.

I assume it would be good enough to have jQuery to somehow prepend html anchor tag (`name="e"`) just before the first occurrence of keyword(s).

Another issue here is: search phrase can (and often will) consist of more than one word. If I choose to go with the first word, what to do when that particular word isn't found (the other ones are)?

So the best approach would be to break the string into separate words, test them for occurrence on a page and prepend the anchor to the first occurrence.

I'm not really a JavaScript/jQuery savvy person so any help would be appreciated.

Here are the scripts:

```
// when the form is submitted, search phrase is written to a "kw" cookie
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var keywords = $("input[name=query]").val();
        $.totalStorage('kw', keywords);
    });
});​
```

In the footer:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var options = {
        exact: "whole",
        style_name_suffix: false,
        keys: $.totalStorage('kw') // keys determine what strings are to be highlighted
    }

    jQuery(document).SearchHighlight(options);


    // I suppose here the value of KW cookie could be broken into words
    // and searching for occurrences could be put
    // along with the code for prepending occurrences with an anchor tag

    // reset KW cookie to empty value
    $.totalStorage('kw', '');
});​
```

Comment: Can you post the `SearchHighlight` function?

Comment: See it here:
http://www.jquery.info/scripts/SearchHighlight.js

I'm not sure if it has to do anything with my intention to have jquery inject anchors but I'd be happy if you give me anything here.

Comment: might be best if you create an html demo in jsfiddle.net showing exactly how you want final output based on some display values

Comment: @A.M.K
Your question makes sense to me now. If that function is able to locate words, it should be possible to modify it so it also puts my anchors before each of them, right?
Seeing anything useful there?

Comment: @charlietfl Here you can see how the HTML should look like after the function does what I need it to: http://jsfiddle.net/developer10/GxvxJ/

Answer (score 0):

Here' a basic starting point that should help. It's still not entirely clear what full objective is. Words are based on your Lorum Ipsum demo. You would need to also modify html output structure. I made words wrap in tag so can visually see effect.

SHould also note that if words match any part of an html tag this code will mess up the html. Regex would need refining to account for htis

```
/* would take this array from your storage plugin*/
var keywords = ['content', 'phrase', 'affordable','another'];
keywords.sort();
var words=[];
/* make new array that includes first letter caps for begiining sentences*/
for ( i=0;i<keywords.length;i++){
    words.push( keywords[i], upperCaseKeyword(keywords[i]));
}
/* get html from content element and store in variable*/
var html = $('.wrapper').html();

for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var word=words[i];    
    var reg = new RegExp(words[i], 'g');
    html = html.replace(reg, '<a name="'+word+'" class="tag">' + word + '</a>');   

}

/* replace old html with modified*/

$('.wrapper').html(html);

/* helper function*/
function upperCaseKeyword(word) {
    var firstLetter = word.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    return firstLetter + word.slice(1);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/GxvxJ/1/

Comment: This looks like it's going in the right direction but note that this piece of HTML code <a name="e"></a> is what I actually need to inject into the HTML markup (before each keyword, or at least before the first occurrence of any of them), it's not supposed to be there before the function is run.
My example markup contained it to demonstrate how it should look like when function has run, but I should have been more specific on that.

Comment: understood...you would need to modify to suit your needs as I noted about modifying output structure

Comment: If I change your fiddle to run in head section instead of "on load", it doesn't work. That seems to be what I need because I tried to put the function into the head function to test in on my site and after that I would move it to footer, where my actual script is.

How should I modify it so it works in the header, or even better, how can I incorporate your function into mine so that nothing gets broken (disregard the fact I need to take array of words from my plugin - I'll do that when I see the script playing nicely with the other one).

Comment: must be wrapped in `$(function(){  /* code*/});`. This is already done in the fiddle by default. Or `$(document).ready(function(){/*code*/})`. You already have both in code above, so inside one of those